# What is proper author order when you write paper based on colleague's work?

Tags: authorship

My colleague has developed a software framework. I have not contributed towards software development but I have been asked by my advisor to write a paper describing the software since my colleague is not experienced in writing.

In this situation, what is the proper order of authors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case

1. Author of the framework
2. you
3. your advisor

but that is strongly dependent on your local and institutions' customs and practices. Ask your advisor informally. When still in doubt, always add yourself second to the first draft. If appropriate, your advisor will suggest moving you to first position, which is a lot less embarrasing than the other way around (your advisor suggesting you should take your name down a notch)